# Search and replace "/" at end of url's using regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Below is my regular expression :-

```
\\bhttps?://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]\\b
```

when the request url is of type `http://www.example.com/` , the last character is not replaced in my shortner url and `/` is appended at end.

The regex is not able to find the last `/`.

Please help with this.

Comment: Why don't you simply use ``if(myString.endsWith("/"))``?

Comment: @vakimshaar, but i want reg exs, they add complexity and make me constipated.

Comment: @Vakimshaar - They add job security. Make the code so complicated that only you understand how it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that / would be a word boundary, so maybe it works better if you add a ? to the and, so it reads:

```
\\bhttps?://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]\\b?
```

Comment: This is working. Its replaces the / at the end. Thanks Edvin. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
if(url.endsWith("/"))
  url = url.substring(0,url.length()-1);
```

or if you need to use regular expressions you can do something like this:

```
url = url.replaceAll("(\\bhttps?://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*)/(\\b?)","$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to replace the trailing `/` (which is what your question directly asks), you can simply do:

```
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Remember to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) often.

Comment: that will erase the previous / if there is not finishing by /

Comment: Is it rocket science for the OP to add an `if` condition before this statement?

Answer (score 0):

**You could simply use:**

```
url = url.replaceAll("\/+$","");
```